# How to add my own datatype in C# program?

Tags: c#, types

Like "int" refers to "Int32" class, "string" refers to "String" class. How to refer a datatype like "abc" to my "Abc" class?

Comment: why would you even want to do that?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - maybe to have a blue font in VS ;)

Comment: to make a datatype which is available for other programmers used my class.

Comment: Give your class a correct name to begin with...A class IS a datatype!

Comment: How is this getting so many upvotes and favorites?  It doesn't make sense...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to people who never worked in C++

Comment: Mitch Wheat, for example I would like a datatype Volts, Watts, Hertz, Celsius for Energy Monitoring

Comment: @Piotr Kula
 : see the accepted answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your "class" is a data type.

The examples you give are the difference between CLR data type names and C# datatype names. They are aliases. C# int maps to CLR Int32 and C# string maps to CLR String.

You can create your own aliases by using "using Xyx=Abc". You must do this in each source file, so it is not that useful.

Comment: I think I should have used CTS here rather than CLR. My bad.

Comment: But visual studio detects my class as a "class" and colored like a class. But datatypes colored different in Visual Studio.

Comment: Incorrect. All classes are data types. VS highlights C# reserved words in dark blue and all other data types in pale blue. THe dark blue highlight is nothing to do with a difference between classes and types.

Answer (score 10):

You can add an alias like this:

```
using abc = MyNamespace.Abc;
```

But I would question why you would want to do this.

[Another poster pointed out a valid use, namely namespace type clashes, but then I would always use the fully qualified type name otherwise it might get very confusing.]

Comment: Creepy...I even used the same namespace name

Comment: @fletcher: aye, that is creepy! Especially since I would never do this! lol!

Comment: Suppose I want to give my class to other programmers to use. If I make my Class like a datatype then they can easily understand and use it like a simple datatype. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As Philip Smith pointed out, your custom class is a data type, and it's members become accessible through that context.

Comment: long time ago, but the answer "WHY" is: Global define a data type like ``C`` for quickly change the type. e.g: ``DBKey = System.UInt32`` or ``DBKey = System.UInt64`` ... or ``DBKey=System.Int32``

Comment: Why?  To produce self documented code.  See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

```
using abc = MyNamespace.Abc;
```

I'm not sure what the advantage of this would be, it's usually used if you find different types with the same name.

Answer (score 5):

You're completely misunderstanding what a "data type" is. In C#, keywords like `int`, `string,` etc. are simply aliases for the corresponding types (implemented as classes/structs) already present in the CLR. For example, `int` has exactly the same meaning as `System.Int32`, which is a struct defined by the core of the .NET framework. Similarly, `string` simply means `System.String`, which is a class.

In .NET, *every* "data type" eventually inherits from `System.Object` (which is aliased as `object` in C#). The data types you refer to are simply pre-implemented classes and structs that inherit from `System.Object`; there's nothing special about them. You should realize that C# does not have special primitive types in the same way that other languages do: they're all just part of a common type hierarchy. The keywords you're used to are simply provided as a convenience.

In essence, **don't worry about it**. Your classes can be used as they are, and this is how they are supposed to be used.

Some reading:

- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24456
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Type_System
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx

Answer (score 2):

types like int, etc are build in types / reserved keywords. Those are defined by the compiler, so it's not possible to add your own.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is probably something you are used to from C++.  There is no equivalent concept in C#.  All you have are the builtin data type.  The only thing you can declare is you own class or struct, but not datatype.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to define custom datatypes in c#
i have the same problem and i searched for the solution with no success
in my case i need to define a datatype for unmanaged types like MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** Why would someone want to do this?

**A:** To produce self documented code.

```
using InternalLoggerName = System.String;
using ExternalLoggerName = System.String;

namespace LoggingUtils
{
  public static class LoggerPool
  {
    private static readonly 
       ConcurrentDictionary
         <
             ExternalLoggerName
           , InternalLoggerName
        >                          LoggerNameMappings 
      = new ConcurrentDictionary<ExternalLoggerName, InternalLoggerName>();


    public static ILog GetLogger(string loggerName)
    {
      // and you don't have to expose the aliases to the outside world
    }
  }
}
```